# Getting "Element type is invalid: expected a string (...)" when trying to use React-bootstrap InputGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to use the "InputGroup" from [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/input-group/). However, when I use InputGroup.Prepend, I get an error saying:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

What I have read from people suffering from similar issues, is that the default export method, or some imports can cause these behaviors. However, applying those solutions to this problem has not resulted in desired the outcome.

Here is my "test.js"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FormControl, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";


export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Home">
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">@</InputGroup.Text>
                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                <FormControl
                    placeholder="Username"
                    aria-label="Username"
                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                />
                </InputGroup>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

And my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import "./App.css";

function App(props) {
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
      if (e !== 'No current user') {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  async function handleLogout() {
    await Auth.signOut();

    userHasAuthenticated(false);

    props.history.push("/login");
  }

  return (
    !isAuthenticating && (
      <div className="App container">
        <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <Link to="/">Scratch</Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              {isAuthenticated ? (
                <>
                  <LinkContainer to="/settings">
                    <NavItem>Settings</NavItem>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <NavItem onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavItem>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                    <NavItem>Signup</NavItem>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <LinkContainer to="/login">
                    <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                  </LinkContainer>
                </>
              )}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <Routes appProps={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }} />
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `<InputGroup.Prepend>` should be undefined. Does it exist? Feels off that it exists next to `<InputGroup>`, but I do not know the framework

Comment: As a matter of fact it looks like that there are some mismatched versions of bootstrap in this project. Currently trying to get everything up to speed. Will update when I finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the documentation for the correct version of Bootstrap I was using. I needed the documentation for [Bootstrap V3](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.com/components/).